# Downloading data from Google maps-based apps

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to download customer’s data in Google maps based app? Like the polygons in this map - http://tromso-parkering.no/parkering/kartoversikt/.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can. I did not check it in detail, but there are some polygons defined in the html source of that page. But are you allowed to download? The page says: "Copyright Tromsø parkering AS".

Comment: I don't need any data from this site. I want to know is it posible and if it is - How to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How? Use a programming language like PHP to fetch the page and regular expressions to extract the data.